# My quill rich text editor is not working when I inject the editor element to the page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On the click of a button on my page, I want to inject a quill rich text editor element into my page. I have the editor element stored in a JavaScript Variable already, and I want to inject the editor element into the page. The issue is that the injected editor element is not functioning again on the page. It seems as if Quill.js is not working again on the element, therefore the element is rendered blank without the necessary features of Quill JS like toolbar, icons, etc. Also, I notice that adding the editor element manually to the page without JavScript's help works perfectly well. I don't know if quill.js is conflicting with the JavaScript. Please Guys am a bit confused here.
The scenario is like this:

**JavaScript variable holding the editor element**

let data = `<div style="height: 700px;" class="mb-0" data-toggle="quill" data-quill-placeholder="Course description" id="course-description"> <h4>Add your lesson content here.</h4> </div>` ;

then I have an h2 element 

### Holding content

 on the page and I want to append the editor element to the h2 element using jquery ( **$(h2).append(data)** ), but the editor element is not working after it has been appended.

I need help figuring out what is the issue here

Comment: You need to manually initialize the editor yourself after you insert the html

Comment: Please can you explain with code? Thanks for your comment tho.

Comment: See the [Configuration docs](https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/). You are probably only used to the httml existing when page loads and the script self initializes then. You need to use the code shown in link after you insert new html